# fire-store and angular post data and images

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, multidimensional-array, push

How can I get uploaded images working with an ng-repeat and how can I get them pushed onto a JSON file for separate sections? Multiple images expected so a multidimensional array.

I'm currently making a website and am trying to load images onto the each section directly. When I make a backup of the site, I'm trying to get the images stored into an array in a JSON file. This is being done through angular. I can get all the other elements of my Angular file to show up and onto the JSON file, but I am struggling with the images.

My problems are the function for adding the images is not working when I have an ng-repeat, and no images are getting binded onto the JSON file. I believe I need a push, but I'm not sure where it would go.

HTML

```
<input type="file" id="imageAdd" />
...
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="image in images">
        <img ng-src="{{ activeItem.image }}" class="img-thumbnail" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

Angular

```
$('#imageAdd').change(function() {
    var file = this.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function() {
        $scope.activeItem.images[0] = reader.result;
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
});
```

JSON

```
var loadedItems = [{"anchor":"Anchor1","description":"Anchor1","$$hashKey":"object:3"},{"anchor":"Anchor2","description":"Anchor2","$$hashKey":"object:4","images":[{}]}];
```

If any more information is needed, let me know.

Comment: Use `$apply()` when you change scope from outside of angular context

Comment: To what are you referring to?

Comment: Use `ng-change` instead of `jQuery`. Documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange